# How to optimize images that are already uploaded in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, image-optimization

I tried reducing the JPEG quality from `/admin/config/media/image-toolkit`. But it did not increase my Page Score.

If there is any other way please let me know.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the proper image styles sizes are used across the site and use [responsive images](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/mobile-guide/responsive-images-in-drupal-8) when possible, but you [won't get 100/100 performance](https://groups.drupal.org/node/517292).